# I can't edit the "Windows" folder even though I am admin

Tags: windows-10

So, all I am trying to do is to change my cursor files to cursors I want. I did cursor schemes but I have to go to settings and re-change them upon every restart of my computer. So I am trying to replace the cursor file in my windows folder instead. However, I can't edit anything even though I am admin. I tried going into the properties of the folder, but all of the permissions I should be able to change are greyed out. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is normal.  You have to break the permission to accomplish this task

Comment: This is not really the way to assign a custom cursor.  See [this](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-change-your-mouse-cursor-pointer/) for the right way.  If you MUST, right click the cursor folder, properties, Security, Advanced.  Change the owner to YOU. Apply and close the window.  Do it again, right click, Properties, Security, now EDIT.  Add yourself with full control.

Comment: Doing this in the way you describe is a literal waste of time.  GUI files within `%WinDir%` are non-editable system files, so whenever `SFC /ScanNow` is run, it will replace the cursor files you've replaced because they will not match the hashes they should match when compared against their backups in the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`).  Since `SFC /ScanNow` should be run once a month, doing this in the way you describe is a literal waste of time.  See Stardock's [CursorFX](https://www.stardock.com/products/cursorfx/) and/or [IconPackager](https://www.stardock.com/products/iconpackager/).

Comment: Where do people get the notion that being an administrator allows them to edit system files willy-nilly?

Answer (score 0):

If changing permissions or disabling UAC (as outlined in Neal's answer) don't work, you can alternatively try booting into a live OS (such as [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/)), and then modifying the required files on your Windows disk.

Keep in mind that this will not work if you have full-disk encryption (such as Bitlocker) enabled on your Windows drive.

Comment: If there is Bitlocker for the drive an option is a WindowsToGo pendrive created by Rufus.

Answer (score -1):

Windows system files cannot be changed because of Windows File Protection. This is something introduced in Windows 2000.

More information about WFP can be found from Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_File_Protection and Microsoft Support article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/222193/description-of-the-windows-file-protection-feature.

Comment: WPF doesn’t stand for Windows File Protection. WPF stands for Windows Presentation Foundation.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, there was a typo in my answer. Corrected.

Answer (score -2):

I believe C: is locked by default since Windows Vista. So this type of behavior is normal. You will need to take the ownership if you want edit this folder while user account control (UAC) is active. To do this press Win+X keys, select file explorer, open computer, find drive C, select properties, go to Security Tab, select your user group that you want to have access and finally click "Edit" to change the permissions.

Alternatively, you can also turn off the UAC through the registry. For instructions, you can check this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/computer-tips/cant-create-file-in-the-c-drive-root-directory-windows-8/). This article is about Windows 8 but this method works with Windows 10 as well.

Comment: I tried this before, but the box for allow/denying certain permissions is greyed out. What do I do? P.S. sorry for the late reply

Comment: Actually, this didn't happen, since I was trying the wrong folder. I was able to select full control, and it scrolled through all of the different files and folders giveing errors saying "access is denied". What do I do now?

Comment: Also, I turned off the UAC and restarted but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can simply change one stupid file without having to go through all this? None of this is working.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not know any other methods apart from disabling UAC or changing permissions.

Comment: Sorry to say.. Disabling the UAC won't give you access to something you don't have access to.  It will just prevent the popup box when account authorization is required.  It will popup process based privilege escalation but won't change ACL file system permissions.